# Want to move MySQL Datadir to another partition

Tags: mysql, configuration, directory, ubuntu-10.04, database-partitioning

I'd like to move all my mysql databases to another parition. I've tried the brazillion guides out there but I've not found anything that works!

Whenever I change the 'datadir' in my.cnf MySQL ceases to function!

```
$ mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Here's some more info:

```
$ mysqld -u root
101110 16:37:03 [Warning] Ignoring user change to 'root' because the user was set to 'mysql' earlier on the command line
101110 16:37:03 [Warning] Can't create test file /home/krainboltgreene/repo/databases/mysql/krainboltgreene-desktop-gateway.lower-test
101110 16:37:03 [Warning] Can't create test file /home/krainboltgreene/repo/databases/mysql/krainboltgreene-desktop-gateway.lower-test
```

And here's the conf file:

https://gist.github.com/672763

Comment: Uhm, it looks like the user your mysqld is running as doesn't have write permission to your new datadir.

Comment: @cdhowie As you can see, the permissions for the ~/repo/databases/mysql file are set to mysql:mysql. > drwxr-xr-x 3 mysql mysql 4.0K 2010-11-10 16:45 mysql

Comment: It may be worth stracing mysqld and see exactly what errno is being set when it tries to create the file.

Comment: Here's the strace: https://gist.github.com/672833

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @cdhowie says, it looks like you may just need to chown your new directory to mysql. This is usually accomplished through `sudo chown -R mysql:mysql directoryname`

Let us know if that works.

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 3 mysql           mysql           4.0K 2010-11-10 16:45 mysql

Comment: As you can see, the permissions for the ~/repo/databases/mysql file are set to mysql:mysql.